# Redirect `http://10.1.10.7:8900/some/long/path` to `mydomain.com` on domain network

Tags: internal-dns

Where I work, we use an enterprise web-based software. To access the different pages, users need to enter a long url, like the one in the title: `http://10.1.10.7:8900/some/long/path`. The different pages are located at `http://10.1.10.7:8900/some/long/path/<specific_page>`. The `/some/long/path` is constant across all the pages users will access.  I want users to be able to enter `website/<specific_page` into a browser instead, where `website` is anything I specify (including something like `ourapp.com`). I want to make it as easy as possible for users to access the different pages because even I have trouble remembering the exact url.

We have a pretty-well established network, with modern networking and server equipment. That includes domain servers with the DNS role installed. I tried quickly adding both A name and CNAME records, but neither of them were what I was looking for (A record is only for an IP address).

Comment: No, you can't do this with DNS.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I didn't necessarily mean accomplishing it with DNS, I brought it up as an example of what I've tried and thought about...